# Upgrading to `polkadot-v0.9.30` throws "no function or associated item named `benchmarks`"

Tags: error

After upgrading a Cumulus based node to use `polkadot-v0.9.30`, and running clippy:

```
cargo +nightly clippy --all --features runtime-benchmarks
```

The following errors are thrown:

```
  error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `benchmarks` found for struct `frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet` in the current scope
      --> runtime/src/lib.rs:1103:4
       |
  1103 |             list_benchmarks!(list, extra);
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet<Runtime>`
       |
       = note: this error originates in the macro `list_benchmark` which comes from the expansion of the macro `list_benchmarks` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `run_benchmark` found for struct `frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet` in the current scope
      --> runtime/src/lib.rs:1135:4
       |
  1135 |             add_benchmarks!(params, batches);
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet<Runtime>`
       |
       = note: this error originates in the macro `add_benchmark` which comes from the expansion of the macro `add_benchmarks` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your `runtime/Cargo.toml` from:

```
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "frame-system-benchmarking",
    ...
]
```

to

```
runtime-benchmarks = [
    "frame-system-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks",
    ...
]
```